# Solving Laplace equations with Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, partial-derivative

I'm following the method in a [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0263822309004693) to solve the following partial differential for $\psi(x,y)$ where $G_x$ and $G_y$ are constants,

$$
G_x(\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial x^2})+G_y(\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial y^2})=0
$$

for this [rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8i6QS.png). What kind of equation is this? I know it's a Laplace equation but is there a more specific category? Is it a homogeneous equation? The boundary conditions for it are

$$
\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}=2y
$$

at $x=0,a$ and

$$
\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial y}=0
$$

at $y=\pm b$. To find $\psi(x,y)$, the authors assume that

$$
\psi(x,y)=\sum_{n=1,3,5...}^{\infty}{f_n(x)\sin(\xi_n y)}
$$

where $f_n(x)$ is a series of undetermined functions and $\xi_n=\frac{n\pi}{2b}$. What kind of equation is the one that they assumed for $\psi(x,y)$? A Fourier series of some sort? They state in the paper that they avoid using hyperbolic functions but in another potential equation for $\psi(x,y)$ that I found in another [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267547369_TORSION_OF_A_RECTANGULAR_PRISMATIC_BAR_SOLUTION_USING_A_POWER_FIT_MODEL) that deals with the same problem is,

$$
\psi(x,y)=xy-\sum_{m=0,1,2...}^{\infty}{c_n\sin(\kappa_nx)\sinh(\kappa_ny)}
$$

where $\kappa_n=\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2a}$. This is also a Fourier series, am I right? Is there a reason why one would want to use one equation for $\psi(x,y)$ over the other?

Comment: In the paper you have cited $G_x$ and $G_y$ are functions of $x$, not constants.

Comment: Yes but for my purposes $G_x$ and $G_y$ are constants. They assume them to be changing but mine is a simpler case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Laplace's equation only if $G_x=G_y\not =0 $. If $G_x\cdot G_y>0$ it is an elliptic equation and if $G_x\cdot G_y<0$ it is hyperbolic equation. In any case it is homogeneous.

The solution suggested is a Fourier series used in the method "separation of variables" for this kind of problems. The type of Fourier series used depends on the problem (equation and boundary conditions), so for different problems one should consider different types of Fourier series.

Comment: Just a clarification about shorthand notation, $\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial x^2}$ can be re-written as $\psi_{xx}$, is that correct? So $\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial x \partial y}$ would be $\psi_{xy}$?

Comment: Yes. (A comment must be 15 characters at least so I had to add this)